# How to print the Key for particular value in python dictionary if more values are present for one key?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
 dic = {'key1': ["value1",  "value2"],
        'key2': ["value4", "value5"] }

 "value4" in [x for v in dic.values() for x in v]
 >> True
```

I want to print the key for value4 instead of True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A python dictionary is optimized for accessing value by key, not the reverse, so here you have no better option than to iterate over all entries in the dict:

```
for key, values in dic.items():
    if 'value4' in values:
        print(key)
        break
```

Comment: for only one value above code will work, if multiple values are present then we have to loop as mentioned below

Comment: The way I understand the question, we are searching with a single value. This approach will also work for more than one value but will be sub optimal if there are multiple queries as pointed out in some of the other answers

Answer (score 1):

For an isolated call, you should iterate `dic` and `break` as per [@IvayloStrandjev's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51243375/9209546).

For repeated calls, it's a good idea to reverse your dictionary to maintain O(1) lookup complexity. Assuming your values are non-overlapping:

```
dic = {'key1': ["value1",  "value2"],
       'key2': ["value4", "value5"]}

dic_reverse = {w: k for k, v in dic.items() for w in v}

print(dic_reverse)

{'value1': 'key1', 'value2': 'key1', 'value4': 'key2', 'value5': 'key2'}
```

Then you can retrieve your key via `dic_reverse.get('value4', None)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter.

```
dic = {'key1': ["value1",  "value2"],
        'key2': ["value4", "value5"] }
filter(lambda x: "value4" in dic[x], dic)         # python 2
list(filter(lambda x: "value4" in dic[x], dic))   # python 3
```

Comment: Python 2.7 I got proper output ['key2'] But in  Python 3 output is <filter object at 0x7f37c8149ba8>

Comment: python3 returns iterator object. so use list(filter(lambda x: "value4" in dic[x], dic))

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
dic = {'key1': ["value1",  "value2"],
        'key2': ["value4", "value5"] }
print( [k for k,v in dic.items() if "value4" in v])
```

**Output:**

```
['key2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want this but here you go -

```
[k for k, v in dic.iteritems() for i in v if i == "value1"]
```

Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: thanks, python3 dic.items  [k for k, v in dic.items() for i in v if i == "value1"]